# Struts2 table creation

Tags: jsp, html-table, struts2, iterator

I have tried this a while before, but I got two columns with adjacent columns having identical data.

```xml
<table bgcolor="white" bordercolor="green" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" align="center">
        <tr bgcolor="green">
            <th>Login Name</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
        </tr>
        <s:iterator value="%{#session.users}" status="usrsts">

                <s:if test="#usrsts.odd==true">
                <tr>
                    <td style="background: gray;"><s:a ><s:property/></s:a></td>
                    </tr>
                </s:if>
                <s:else>
                    <td style="background: white;"><s:property /></td>
                </s:else>

        </s:iterator>
</table>
```

The problem is I couldn't make it as a two column table it prints as single column table itself.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this should do it:

```xml
<table bgcolor="white" bordercolor="green" border="1" 
       cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" align="center">
    <tr bgcolor="green">
        <th>Login Name</th>
        <th>Full Name</th>
    </tr>
    <s:iterator value="%{#session.users}" status="usrsts">
       <s:if test="#usrsts.odd==true">
            <tr style="background: gray;">
       </s:if>
       <s:else>
            <tr style="background: white;">
       </s:else>
                <td ><s:a><s:property value="username"/></s:a></td>
                <td ><s:property value="fullname"/></td>
           </tr>
    </s:iterator>
</table>
```

Comment: I think the problem is related to iterator every time its creates a new row for print data..